# Django settings.py Parentheses vs Square Brackets

Tags: python, django

Is there a functional difference between using parentheses vs square brackets in the settings files of django?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  ...
]
```

vs

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.admin',
  ...
)
```

There does not appear to be, but I just wanted confirmation.

Comment: No. One is a list and the other is a tuple, but in this case all that matters is that they are iterable, so it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. It's just a python stuff though. Tuples `( )` are immutable while lists `[ ]` are mutable. Some might want to do as follows.

```
INSTALLED_APPS += os.environ["APP_ADDITIONAL_APPS"].split(",")
```

It's just impossible when you use tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I like that the answer above includes the docs, but this is more thorough regarding how/why it might impact the rest of the system.  I've been debugging an issue and thought this might be a part of it; but it as far as I'm hearing it doesn't seem it will be.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) define an empty list as default argument. Even if there's no functional difference, I'd rather recommend using list `[]`.